# UTF-8 with BarcodeLib

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode

I'm trying to make a small WinForm app using BarcodeLib.dll and it works fine but when I'm trying to type Arabic(UTF-8) text the BarcodeLib can't generate the image needed and gave me "Invalid Setting" .

Any one can help?
Thanks!

Comment: Text itself doesn't have a particular encoding. You can convert Arabic text *to* UTF-8, but that's a different matter. What barcode format are you using, and does it even define what the behaviour should be for non-ASCII text?

Comment: I'm using Code 128 Auto but can't understand the last part of your question.

Comment: Code 128 barcodes do not support UTF-8 text, only standard ASCII and Latin-1 characters defined in ISO/IEC 8859-1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

Comment: Sadly I can't find ISO/IEC in BarcodeLib. Is there is a alternative way to do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which BarcodeLib you’re referring to? http://barcode.com/ or https://github.com/bbarnhill/barcodelib ?